# Can't open image in Android

Tags: android, image, exif

I'm developing an application in android and I'm having a problem to show some imagens downloaded from an http server.
Here's the code for the download:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URI.create(imageURL));
        httpGet.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"), "UTF-8", false));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream input = responseEntity.getContent();
        // Get the bitmap
        Options opt = new Options();
        opt.inScaled = true;
        opt.inDensity = 1;
        opt.inTargetDensity = 1;
        opt.inPreferQualityOverSpeed = false;
        opt.inPurgeable = true;
        opt.inSampleSize = 2;
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, opt);

        // Save the bitmap to the file
        String path = SMVAndroid.IMAGE_PATH;
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        File file = new File(path, fileName.concat(".jpeg"));
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        /*int byteRead;
        while((byteRead = input.read()) != -1){
            fOut.write(byteRead);
        }*/

        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
```

Some of the imagens does not download using this method, so I tried the commented code and it does download, but I can't show it on an ImageView component.
I've tried to see if the image was in a different format (despite the extension) and using a program called trid (http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) I've discovered that the images that doesn't work are identified as jpeg-exif and the ones that work are just jpeg. I've downloaded the images in my PC and used a program to read exif information and the ones that works does not have any information. I've concluded the problem could be this information, but when I took a photo with an android cellphone, it saves this information in the file too, so I don't know what can be this problem.
I've tried to view the image in the android browser too and it does not work. It does not work in the native image viewer too. I could manage to see the image just in the chrome browser for android, but when I try to download them using the browser it does not download.
Does anyone knows if the problem is the exif?
I've uploaded the image here:
http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/5977/1007e.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The problem was not the Exif information. It was the color type of the image. It seems android can't read images with the CMYK format. I've converted to RGB and it opened. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Exif is the problem. Android does provide ExifInterface to read exif data from jpg image. Try to read exif data via ExifInterface and see what you get.

Comment: I can try this, but it won't solve my problem, since I can't donwload it from my app.

Comment: It shows some of the information there, but I can't open the image even in the native gallery.

Comment: Kindly read following three discussions. Your problem may be solved by one of these:-
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9064
http://code.google.com/p/skia/issues/detail?id=69
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066